# How to dynamically adjust the throughput of an Observable pipeline?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Please, observe the following C# code snippet:

```
dir.EnumerateFiles("*." + ext, searchOption)
    .ToObservable()
    .Select(file => GetBatchSource(file, ...))
    .Merge(maxConcurrentFiles)
    .Select(batch => WriteBatch(batch, ...))
    .Merge(maxConcurrentBatches)
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    .GetAwaiter()
    .GetResult();

...

private static IObservable<Batch> GetBatchSource(FileInfo file, ...)
{ ... }

private static IObservable<Unit> WriteBatch(Batch batch, ...)
{ ... }
```

Where:

- GetBatchSource parses the lines of the given file and produces batches of them as it goes
- WriteBatch - writes the given batch into the database

This code parses and dumps log files into a database, while reading no more than `maxConcurrentFiles` log files at the same time and writing no more than `maxConcurrentBatches` batches to the database.

My problem is that `maxConcurrentFiles` and `maxConcurrentBatches` are fixed values. They are, of course, parameters of the tool, but once given they do not change.

Ideally, I would like to strike a perfect balance between the speed with which batches are produced (controlled by `maxConcurrentFiles`) and with which they are persisted (controlled by `maxConcurrentBatches`). But this speed is not constant.

I have run the code with both `maxConcurrentFiles` and `maxConcurrentBatches` equal to 1 and noticed that the number of produced batches waiting to be written is never constant. At the beginning it seems to climb to about 6 batches and oscillate between 5 and 6. Then, for some reason, it climbs to 10 (as if database is slowing down) then gradually goes down to 0 (now the file reading logic is slowing down and the database is idle), oscillates between 0 and 2, then climbs again and so forth. The amount of batches waiting in the queue may climb up to 47!

Anyway, I need a solution where the amount of concurrent batches written to the database is increased as the number of batches in the queue increases. Similarly, the amount of concurrent files needs to be increased as the database becomes idle waiting for batches.

How would you go about implementing a thing like that?

Comment: so you want to set a limit on the number of "in-flight" batches and relax the other two?

Comment: I dont think this is where Rx shines, however it is (IMO) where queues do shine.

Comment: @LeeCampbell is on the money. While it doesn't answer the question, this doesn't seem a great fit for a reactive approach - you seem to be in total control of the source events (the files) - so I'd go for an async enumerable approach. It's a classic case where the appearance of back-pressure indicates you aren't really reactive. There's a lot of external factors that will affect these numbers anyway so it's highly unlikely you'll control them. "Pulling" rather than "pushing" will give you the control you need. There's no apparent benefit to switching from `IEnumerable` to  `IObservable` here.